# Expose socket via web sockets

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a server that creates a socket on port 8181. I would like to access that socket from a web page opened in Google Chrome 14. I suppose it is not possible in a straight manner. Chrome provides support for Web Sockets but not for standard sockets. Is that right?

Is is possible to somehow create an intermediary that would expose my socket server listening on port 8181 as a web socket server running on some other port?

Comment: In Node.js, you can create both a server and a client. You could make an application that includes both a WebSockets server on port, say, 8182, and a client that connects to port 8181. You simply route all incoming data (after decoding the WebSockets format) to 8181, and all data received from 8181 you convert into WebSockets format and pass through to the client (Chrome).

Comment: I'd like more detail. Are you building your own server? Using a server like Tomcat or Apache? The GlassFish application server includes grizzly, which is a websocket server. I'm just investigating it now. The bad news (should not last forever) is that I haven't found any working examples yet.

Comment: @mgamer, has your question been answered sufficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) is a generic WebSockets to TCP socket proxy/bridge. I created websockify originally to allow [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) (HTML5 VNC client) to be able to connect to an unpatched VNC server. But it is generically useful (not VNC specific) so I spun it off as a separate project.

On a UNIX/Linux system you would run websockify like this:

```
./websockify 8080 my_server:8181
```

Port 8080 in the above example is the port to listen for WebSocket connections. my_server is the name/IP of your system where you have a server listening on port 8181. If you are running websockify on the same system as your server then you can just use `localhost` in place of 'my_server'.

The websockify project also comes with a Javascript wrapper library called websock.js. websockify supports the new protocol versions (used by Chrome 14+ and Firefox 6+) but it also works with older versions. However, with the older versions of the protocol there is no way to send raw binary data (only UTF-8), so websock.js and websockify work together to base64 encode/decode the data (between the browser and websockify) when using the older protocol so that you can still send raw binary data to/from the target.

Comment: But based on the documentation at the website link, it won't work with Chrome 14.

Comment: @RogerF.Gay, not sure what website info you are referring to but websockify works just fine with Chrome 14. WebSockify works with both Hixie versions and all HyBi versions of the protocol (i.e. it works with all browsers with any sort of WebSockets support).

Comment: BTW, I've updated the websockify README to be more clear on protocol and binary data support.